# Nginx, uWSGI, Flask app doesn't show changes until the server is restarted

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

Every time I update my Python file, I have to reboot the server to see changes. I have tried restarting Nginx and uWSGI with no luck. Flask is running in debug mode. How can I see changes without rebooting the entire server?

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask
import time
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
   return "Hello cob at " + time.time().__str__() + "\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`uwsgi.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
socket = :9090
plugin = python
wsgi-file = /home/vagrant/PythonVision/app.py
process = 3
callable = app
```

`nginx.conf`

```
server {
  location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9090;
  }
}
```

I am testing this with these steps:

- change the return message from "Hello cob" to "hello bob", save the file
- Refresh the page in a browser (clear cache of browser) No change
- Do sudo service uwsgi restart, sudo service nginx restart
- Refresh the page in a browser (clear cache of browser) No change

Comment: I suspect that there's something wrong with your uWSGI or nginx config. Can you see if there's any error log when you restart uWSGI and nginx?

Comment: If there was a issue why would the restart show ok as a status on the right? Plus it would then fail to render any content?

Comment: Changing code in the vagrant instant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, one way I got around this was to do this in my uwsgi.ini file

touch-reload = /home/vagrant/PythonVision/app.py

Then I touch the file app.py and BANG sorted

Answer (score 1):

To actually run your flask app in debug mode, you run this command:

`python /home/vagrant/PythonVision/app.py`

Then you can go on your browser: http://ip:5000/.

Since I know you're running this on vagrant, the `ip` might be defined by your configs, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: But if they're running it via some WSGI server, it very well might not update. Running in debug mode will automatically reload new source files.

Comment: sudo service uwsgi restart? is that not the right command.  I hear somewhere there or .pyc files?

Comment: I did service uwsgi restart without sudo and still no update

Comment: Surely I have listed that, the simplest py file, simple uwsgi and simple Nginx file

Comment: @Burf2000 is this your prod setup or dev setup? are you trying to see changes on your dev machine? how is your deployment setup?

Comment: This is my dev setup to learn the basics of using Python as a api. My real machine does not have anything install except vagrant

Comment: @Burf2000 have you tried running the flask app directly, like I posted on my solution? That's how dev environments run, no caching layer, no multi-processes, easier to use a debugger, the list goes on.

Comment: Doesnt really help with what I want to do